# Uncaught ReferenceError: Sys is not defined for menu

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

This problem has arose from a different question I asked where I was trying to figure out why my navigation menu in my asp.net website was loading vertically instead of horizontally sometimes. After working through that problem and thinking that I fixed the problem, the problem came back up again, and this time I noticed through the google chrome developer tools that It was showing this Sys is not defined error which appears to control my navigation menu. Here is where the code is throwing the error

```
<script type='text/javascript'>new Sys.WebForms.Menu({ element: 'NavigationMenu', disappearAfter: 500, orientation: 'horizontal', tabIndex: 0, disabled: false });</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

theForm.oldSubmit = theForm.submit;
theForm.submit = WebForm_SaveScrollPositionSubmit;

theForm.oldOnSubmit = theForm.onsubmit;
theForm.onsubmit = WebForm_SaveScrollPositionOnSubmit;
//]]>
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This code in developer tools is located at the very bottom of the master page code file that the webpage references. What is confusing me tho is that, if i go to edit my MasterPage file in Visual Web Developer, the code below is not included so I don't know how I can edit this.

Below is my entire master page code

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Site.Master.vb" Inherits="Site" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="~/Pictures/PBradleyFavicon.ico" />


<link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />



<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">

</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<style type="text/css" runat="server">
.textBox
{
 text-align: right;
 margin-top:10px;
 margin-right:10px;
 float:Right;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form runat="server">
  <div class="header" dir="ltr">
        <div class="title">
        </div> 
        <div class="Logo">
        <table style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 15px;">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="top">
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" Height="64px" 
                            ImageUrl="~/Pictures/PBradleyJCBLogo.jpg" PostBackUrl="~/jcb.aspx" 
                            style="margin-left: 0px" Width="321px" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="hideSkiplink">

        <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false"
            IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Items>
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/" Text="Home" />
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Used_Equipment.aspx" Text="Equipment">
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/New_Equipment.aspx" Text="New Equipment"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Used_Equipment.aspx" Text="Used Equipment"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/jcb.aspx" Text="JCB Skid Steers"></asp:MenuItem>

                </asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Sprayer_Parts.aspx" Text="Online Parts" >
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Sprayer_Parts.aspx" Text="Sprayer Parts" />
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="https://www.allpartsstore.com/index.htm?customernumber=VA2352" Text="Aftermarket Tractor Parts" />
                </asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Plastic_Supplies.aspx" Text="Plastic Supplies" />
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Video.aspx" Text="Customer Corner">
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Video.aspx" Text="Video Lounge"></asp:MenuItem>

                </asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Contact.aspx" Text="Contact Us" />
            </Items>
        </asp:Menu>
    </div>
        <asp:Panel ID="p" runat="server" DefaultButton="ImageButton1">         
           <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1"
                runat="server" CssClass="textBox" Height="22px" 
            ImageUrl="~/Pictures/SearchIcon2.png" Width="22px" />   
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="textBox" 
            style="margin-top: 11px" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>

            </asp:Panel>



    </div>

<div class="page">

    <div class="main">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer" align="left">

    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Font-Size="Small" 
        ForeColor="#3E6FFF" NavigateUrl="~/">Home</asp:HyperLink>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink8" runat="server" Font-Size="Small" 
        ForeColor="#3E6FFF" NavigateUrl="~/New_Equipment.aspx">New Equipment</asp:HyperLink>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" Font-Size="Small" 
        ForeColor="#3E6FFF" NavigateUrl="~/Used_Equipment.aspx">Used Equipment</asp:HyperLink>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" runat="server" Font-Size="Small" 
        ForeColor="#3E6FFF" NavigateUrl="~/Sprayer_Parts.aspx">Sprayer Parts</asp:HyperLink>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" runat="server" Font-Size="Small" 
        ForeColor="#3E6FFF" NavigateUrl="~/Plastic_Supplies.aspx">Plastic Supplies</asp:HyperLink>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink6" runat="server" Font-Size="Small" 
        ForeColor="#3E6FFF" NavigateUrl="~/Video.aspx">Videos</asp:HyperLink>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink7" runat="server" Font-Size="Small" 
        ForeColor="#3E6FFF" NavigateUrl="~/Contact.aspx">Contact Us</asp:HyperLink>
        <br />
    Address: 750 Massanutten St Harrisonburg, VA 22802<br />
    Phone: (540) 434-2352&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <br />
    Copyright © Web Design by Nick Fulk. All Rights Reserved<br />

</div>
</form>
```

I can provide other code if necessary I'm just not exactly sure what else would be needed. If anyone can help me figure out why I'm getting this error on my page load and how to fix it I would appreciate it.

And one last thing to mention. I can't find where any script files are located in my project, I believe asp adds a bunch of default ones such as the (Webresource.axd) but don't know where they are located

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finally finding a solution to what was causing this issue. I did not have a script manager running on the page that was having issues loading the menu so when my page was loading, it was hitting this error before the menu finished loading so it would not complete.

This part of the code

```
<script type='text/javascript'>new Sys.WebForms.Menu({ element: 'NavigationMenu', disappearAfter: 500, orientation: 'horizontal', tabIndex: 0, disabled: false });</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Apparently is compiled by the script manager (sorry if compiled isn't the correct term, feel free to correct me).

So I fixed the problem by added a script manager to my MasterPage and everything is working how it should.